# Function app restarts every hour + 4 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a v2 function app written in C# that is deployed to azure. I have application insights monitoring set up to monitor it. I'm looking at the logs to try and diagnose some performance issues and I'm noticing a bunch of messages like this:

```
Host started (xyz ms)
```

I see one of these messages every hour + 4 minutes.

```
7/9/2019, 8:27:04 AM - TRACE
7/9/2019, 7:23:03 AM - TRACE
7/9/2019, 6:19:02 AM - TRACE
7/9/2019, 5:15:03 AM - TRACE
etc.
```

I have a function that runs on a trigger that I'm using to keep the function alive so I can avoid cold starts, which end up in really slow function calls when it first starts.

```
[FunctionName("KeepAlive")]
public void Run([TimerTrigger("30 */4 * * * *", RunOnStartup=true)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Keep Alive");
}
```

I thought that with this function running every 4 minutes it would prevent my function app from shutting down, but for some reason it is restarting every hour + four minutes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the following information so we can investigate from back end?

- Function App version (1.0 or 2.0)
- Function App name
- Function name(s) (as appropriate)
- Region

If you don't want to give your function app name, you can do so privately.https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT function app is 2.0. Region is CentralUS. 8c95b992-e564-4b06-9367-2b04b6aa5983 is the execution id. Timestamp is 2019-07-10T12:55:14.792

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT were you able to see my function?

Answer (score 0):

From the back-end logs of 9th and 10th July, there were no restarts.
All these functions and rest of the function executed successfully without a single failure.

Sta*****Function

Mo*****st

Physical*******List

We have detected that you are running with the default setting of logging sampling enabled for Application Insights. This could cause missing execution logs from your monitor logs.

Enable the application insights logging sampling might lead to:

- Timer Trigger executions missing from your monitor logs
- Other data log missing

You may just need to adjust the sampling settings to fit your particular monitoring scenario.

[Please review this guidance to configure sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-sampling).

Also runOnStartup is enabled. **We recommend against setting runOnStartup to true in production.**

The function will be invoked when the runtime starts. This might lead to unscheduled executions in the execution list below.

[Please check here to disable runOnStartup configuration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#configuration)

Comment: I don't understand why I'm seeing so many Host started messages in the logs then? Is that not equivalent to the function app restarting? I'm seeing one every hour. If they are not the same, then what is the distinction?